# What is the best way to validate if a record exists in two tables?

Tags: validation, sql-server-2012

I have a table which I update with new data each month.  Sometimes there is a new Location value that comes in the data.  I have another table that holds all the detailed information about a Location that I need to make sure that the new Location value exists.  What is the best way to do that validation?

The data table name is SCM and the location detail table name is LocationDetail.

The field name from SCM is Location and the field name from LocationDetail is LocationCode.

If the new Location is not in the LocationDetail table, I need to know so I can add it in, so I am looking for a query that will show me all the locations from the SCM table that are not in the LocationDetail table.

Comment: This could be as simple as a LEFT OUTER JOIN, checking for null. You need to read up on LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty

```
select * from SCM 
where Location not in (
    select LocationCode from LocationDetail
)
```